# How to check when web server is down on EC2 aws

Tags: amazon-ec2, alarm, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I have installed a web server on the ec2 instance and I want to get notified using SNS when a server is down for whatever reason. Please suggest some solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an ELB in front of your EC2 instance then configure it with a "health-check".  You can then link the health-check to an SNS topic so that when the health-check fails you get notified via SNS.

Comment: I also read somewhere that apply alarm checks on CPU utilization that when it exceeds to 100 its mean server is down. Does this solution work?
by the way thank you for you solution. I will tes it.

Comment: Yes you can apply CloudWatch alarms to the EC2 instances and connect them to SNS topics and associate your cell phone with the topic.

Comment: Does only checking CPU utilization at 0 and 100 thresholds will ensure that server is down?

Comment: No. The server can be down for lots of reasons. The ELB healthcheck will trigger an alarm if the server is responding with 5xx errors or 4xx errors. CPU utilization has nothing to do with the server being down but if CPU utilizaiton is really really high like 60% then the server may be moving slow and bottlenecked for some reason that needs inspection.